# JavaScript Fetch: characters with encoding issues

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, fetch-api

I'm trying to use Fetch to bring some data into the screen, however some of the characters ares showing a weird � sign which I believe has something to do with converting special chars.

When debugging on the server side or if I call the servlet on my browser, the problem doesn't happen, so I believe the issue is with my JavaScript. See the code below:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type','text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

fetch('getrastreiojadlog?cod=10082551688295', myHeaders)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });
```

I think it is probably some detail, but I haven't managed to find out what is happening. So any tips are welcome
Thx

Comment: look there..  and other  https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [response's text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) function always decodes the payload as utf-8.

If you want the text in other charset you may use [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) to convert the [response buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) (NOT the text) into a decoded text with chosen charset.

Using your example it should be:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type','text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

fetch('getrastreiojadlog?cod=10082551688295', myHeaders)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.arrayBuffer();
        })
        .then(function (buffer) {
            const decoder = new TextDecoder('iso-8859-1');
            const text = decoder.decode(buffer);
            console.log(text);
        });
```

Notice that I'm using `iso-8859-1` as decoder.

Credits: [Schneide Blog](https://schneide.blog/2018/08/08/decoding-non-utf8-server-responses-using-the-fetch-api/)

Comment: I had a similar problem with my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195466/node-fetch-api-and-blob-to-convert-windows-1252-characters-to-utf-8. The code works also in node.js using the node-fetch API.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server isn't returning an utf-8 encoded response, try to find which charset is used and then modify it in call headers.
Maybe ISO-8859-1 :

```
myHeaders.append('Content-Type','text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Comment: Hi Nil,
Thx for the reply. I'm running it locally in my machine and the POM file is set with <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>. So that means it should be working with UTF enconding right?

Comment: POM file? That's java / maven back-end right? I'm not familiar with these environments but I'm pretty sure they use ISO-8859-1 as default encoding.  The project.build.Source is more like to be the input (source) encoding, and I've no id how to manage output encoding for your backend.  But maybe you can try the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder)TextDecoder Class in javascript :

Comment: Yes, you are correct on both statments. That's why we need to explicitly say that it is utf-8. Since it doesn't happen by openning the URL in the browser and it does when using fetch(), could it be something on the fetch header or something like it?

Comment: have you tried "<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>" in your POM?

Comment: Just did, unfortunatly it didn't work... Shame, I was quite hopeful with that one

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was in how ther servlet was serving the data without explicitly informing the enconding type on the response.
By adding the following line in the Java servlet:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

it was possible got get the characters in the right format.